# Realm: Update Object without updating lists

Tags: ios, swift, realm, objectmapper

Is there a way to update an object without deleting it's lists with ObjectMapper?

For example:

I have a `User` model:

```
class User: Object, ObjectMapper {
  dynamic var id: Int = 0
  dynamic var name: String = ""

  var locations = List<Location>()

  convenience required init?(map: Map) {
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {
    id        <- map["id"]
    name      <- map["name"]
    locations <- (map["locations"], ListTransform<Location>())
  }
}
```

Now if I get the user data from the server, I don't get the locations every time for efficiency reasons. But if I initialize the user without them and save it with `add(user, update: true)` all locations get deleted since no locations where found in the JSON data.

What's the best and cleanest way to update the attributes of the User object but not it's relations?

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch the existing User from Realm and then change its attributes, that way you can keep previously saved locations.

Answer (score 0):

Empty values are still considered valid input, so if you're passing in a JSON string where `locations` is present but empty, Realm is assuming this means you want to delete everything in there.

The easiest way to avoid this is to make sure that an empty key called `locations` isn't being passed to Realm. Realm will only update properties you explicitly provide. You can try removing it from the JSON file if it's present, or modifying your ObjectMapper logic to skip it if it's detected that it is empty.

Comment: Can you explain more about how to make ObjectMapper skip empty fields?
ObjectMapper by default initializes objects with empty fields, even if i specify that I want to ignoreNils in the mapping. So when I parse the response, I get a new object with some empty fields and it is passed to realm to update/merge the existing object, which overrides my existing fields.

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry. I'm not too sure. If ObjectMapper explicitly initializes every field, even if it's not provided in the JSON, then that would come into conflict with the way Realm assumes which fields to touch. I'd recommend seeing if you can have a look at ObjectMapper's code to see if there's a way to disable that behaviour.